# Как вычитать из даты дату? и получить количество месяцев и лет?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть у меня поле "employment_date" - дата зачисления человека на работу
с типом date.

Мне нужно узнать сколько он проработал месяцев и лет (по логике):
current date - employment_date

Вопрос: как мне из этого вытянуть года и месяцы???

Comment: Давайте проверим вашу логику: если я устроился на работу 1 марта, а сегодня 31 марта, то какой результат? А если 1 февраля а сегодня 1 марта?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833176/postgresql-days-months-years-between-two-dates